# Add failover to Java microservice

Tags: java, microservices, failover

I have a Java miroservice, which will be deployed as multiple service instances. The microservice works statelessly in a simple way: fetch a request according to predefined criteria from DB, process the request, fetch next and process it, and so on. 
I consider now to add failover to the service. I might need add extra information(like processor_id) to the request if it's processed by some instance. So if the instance is determined without response, the request can be taken by other instances. I also need add heartbeat to the microservice. Maybe I can leverage Apache Zookeeper or Curator to achieve this.
But I don't know how to make different pieces work together. It'll be better if there are examples in Java.

Answer (score 1):

What i have seen in my career is that there is a load balancer to distribuite the requests across the microservices. The load balancer knows the availability of the microservices invoking a status end point which returns an http status. If there is no response, or the response is negative, the load balancer excludes the microservice form the group.

Comment: How to customize a response to the load balancer?

Comment: In fact, in my case, I might not need a load balancer to  distribute requests, because each instance will fetch a request forever and sometimes compete for same request.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean with "because each instance will fetch a request forever and sometimes compete for same request.", Your clients need to reach your microservice at a given address, lets say www.myapp.com/my/end/point at that address a load balancer should redirect the request internally to one of the nodes in which your microservice is deployed.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. The microservice has two public interfaces:sumit and query. Both implementations are very simple: for submit, just add request to DB; for query, just query result from DB. Most work in the service are request processing, which is not public. Of course, I need use loadbalancer for the two public interfaces.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant I don't know how to use the loadbalancer for request processing part, in fact the processor fetches request entry from DB and processes it, then repeats processing the next. Each deployed instance works in the same way. So requests can be processed distributely. Now I want to add failover feature for the microservice. I'm considering to use Apache Curator/Zookeeper to register and discover service.

Comment: Forgot to say, the request processor uses a dedicated thread to process requests infinitely.